Can not get label color from Premiere pro using extend script
I want to use Extend script to get the color of the labels of the clips in a Premiere pro sequence.
However, I keep getting “undefined”.
The clips in the sequence are labeled with various colors as shown in the image.
I have looked in various explanatory articles, but I could not find the answer.
If you could tell me how to do this, I would appreciate it.
What the Console Displays↓
3 undefined 4
var project = app.project ; var sequence = project.activeSequence ; 
$ .writeln ( sequence.videoTracks.numTracks ) ; 
$ .writeln ( sequence.videoTracks [ 0 ] .clips [ 0 ] .labels ) ; $ .writeln ( sequence.audioTracks.numTracks ) ;

enter image description here
There is not a lot of information on this programming language, so I had a hard time finding it, but when I displayed the result in the console using Premier Pro's Extend Script reference, it was displayed as undefined.
According to the reference, a number should be rained down for each label color, but I cannot get that number.
